# Creating a new data frame with calculations from an existing data frame using R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am looking to create a new data frame of averages based off a population data frame.  Column A is a list of ages followed by the population of each for a number of years.  I am wondering what the best approach to creating a new data frame with the average age for each year. The formula I am using to calculate the average is sum(age*year)/sum(year)

For example this is what I have:

```
Age | 2000 | 2001 | 2002 
------------------------
2   | 4    | 1    | 2   
3   | 6    | 3    | 5  
4   | 10   | 9    | 8
```

and I would like a new data frame like this:

```
Year| Avg_age 
--------------
2000 | 3.3    
2001 | 3.6
2002 | 3.4
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) and [Run a custom function on a data frame in R, by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431322/run-a-custom-function-on-a-data-frame-in-r-by-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can reshape to 'long' format and get the `summarise`d output grouped by 'Year'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -Age, names_to = 'Year') %>%
   group_by(Year) %>%
   summarise(Avg_age = sum(Age * value)/sum(value), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Year  Avg_age
#* <chr>   <dbl>
#1 2000     3.3 
#2 2001     3.62
#3 2002     3.4
```

---

Or it can be done in reverse as well i.e. first get the summarised output and then do the reshaping

```
df1 %>%
   summarise(across(-Age, ~  sum(Age * .)/sum(.))) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = 'Year', 
        values_to = 'Avg_age')
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Year  Avg_age
#  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 2000     3.3 
#2 2001     3.62
#3 2002     3.4
```

---

Or using `dapply` with `stack`

```
library(collapse)
stack(dapply(df1[-1], function(x) sum(x * df1$Age)/sum(x)))[2:1]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Age = 2:4, `2000` = c(4, 6, 10), `2001` = c(1, 
3, 9), `2002` = c(2, 5, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```