# R: How to subset DFs according to unique values in column and loop each of them in the function?

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, dplyr

I want to create a loop function, which subset data according to a unique value in Category column, so to have separated DF**s** where `Category == "A", Category == "B",....     Category == "F"

```
data <- structure(list(Category = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
"D", "E", "E", "E", "C", "A", "B", "B", "F", "F"), Sales = c(34L, 
32L, 34L, 56L, 32L, 66L, 6L, 55L, 66L, 56L, 3L, 43L, 56L, 65L, 
34L, 65L, 43L), Year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))

   Category Sales Year
1         A    34 2015
2         A    32 2015
3         B    34 2015
4         B    56 2015
5         C    32 2016
6         C    66 2016
7         C     6 2016
8         D    55 2016
9         E    66 2017
10        E    56 2017
11        E     3 2017
12        C    43 2017
13        A    56 2018
14        B    65 2018
15        B    34 2018
16        F    65 2018
17        F    43 2018
```

and after throwing all these unique DFs into function, for example:

```
divide <- function(df) {
  Sales <- (Sales - 32) * 5 / 9
  return(df)
}

data <- divide(data)
```

and after looping all these DFs, combine them using `rbind()`

All these need to be automatized, I can't code and subset DFs manually for every unique value in the Category column. So I need to use `unique()` function

P.S
This is not the original function I posted here! It is just an example. But the idea is to subset DFs with unique values in the Category column, throw them into the function and combine rbind() in the end

Comment: This is very unclear, what is your expected output? Why not applying the function by group?

Comment: The idea is to subset separated DFs, where there is only Category A, B ...or F; throw them into the function and combine all these returns using rbind()

Comment: If you group by Category  (`dplyr::group_by(Category)`) you can then apply a function to each one of them separately, as @Maël sugested. Check the `map` family.

Comment: This is not the original function I posted here! It is just an example. But the idea is to subset DFs with unique values in the Category column, throw them into the function and combine rbind() in the end

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't see the need to split into different data.frames and then recompose the original dataset after applying the same function to all new subsets.

Answer (score 2):

You can:

- Use `split` to split your data according to the unique Categories.
- Use `lapply` to apply a function to each of your dataset (here, I created a new variable, `sumYear`).
- Use `do.call` to get back to your original dataframe

```r
divide <- function(var) {
  (var - 32) * 5 / 9
}

split(data, data$Category) |>
  lapply(function(x) transform(x, Sales = divide(x$Sales))) |>
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, args = _)
```

```r
     Category      Sales Year
A.1         A   1.111111 2015
A.2         A   0.000000 2015
A.13        A  13.333333 2018
B.3         B   1.111111 2015
B.4         B  13.333333 2015
B.14        B  18.333333 2018
B.15        B   1.111111 2018
C.5         C   0.000000 2016
C.6         C  18.888889 2016
C.7         C -14.444444 2016
C.12        C   6.111111 2017
D           D  12.777778 2016
E.9         E  18.888889 2017
E.10        E  13.333333 2017
E.11        E -16.111111 2017
F.16        F  18.333333 2018
F.17        F   6.111111 2018
```

---

Note that this is not a very straightforward way to apply a function by group. You could use `dplyr::group_by` or `ave` in base R to do so; see e.g. solutions of this question: [Run a custom function on a data frame in R, by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431322/run-a-custom-function-on-a-data-frame-in-r-by-group).

Comment: instead of:  lapply(function(x) transform(x, sumYear = sum(Year))) |, I need to specify 'divide' function in advance and next apply split(data, data$Category) |> to it. Something like this:              split(data, data$Category) |>
  lapply(divide()) |>
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, args = _)

Comment: Does not work: Error: unexpected input in:
"  lapply(function(x) divide(x)) |> 
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, args = _"

Comment: This is because your function is at the variable level, not the dataframe. You can use transform in that case. See my edit

Comment: Have you run it? There is a still error

Comment: Right, this time it should work. I changed the function as well, which not clearly formulated.