# Cox Regression (survival package) and stratification on a variable

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm doing a Cox Regression on risk of all-cause mortality as a function of a physical activity, and I want to do a stratified analysis on socioceonomic status. I have created a factor variable containing all socioeconomic classes (low, medium, and high).

Is there a way to do a stratified analysis **without** filtering on socioeconomic class, creating three different dataframes and do the analysis as one usually would using the coxph() function from the survival package?

Suggestions for other packages with functions that fit my wish is gladly appreciated.

Comment: Split dataframe on "socioeconomic" column, then apply the function, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431322/run-a-custom-function-on-a-data-frame-in-r-by-group

Comment: Thanks for directing me to that old post.

Comment: Did the solutions from that post help to get an answer to your question?

Comment: Yup! I did some modifications though, I added my solution as a comment to the post if you’re interested.